# Operate on multiple rows based on a condition from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/11
The result table needs a 6th column, shipping_price, that has the value 250 in the first two rows and the value 200 in rows 3, 4 and 5:

- 750-(100 * 1 + 200 * 2)=250
- 850-(150 * 2 + 50 * 3 + 200 * 1)=200

How do I create that column?

Comment: you can create a view for this calculation https://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to calculate the "product" total:

```
sum(orders_products.product_price * orders_products.product_quantity) over (partition by orders.order_id) as order_total
```

Then I would write this logic as:

```
SELECT o.order_id, op.product, op.product_price, op.product_quantity,
       o.order_total,
       o.order_total - sum(op.product_price * op.product_quantity) over (partition by o.order_id)
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     orders_products op
     ON o.order_id = op.order_id;
```

Note that `orders` is first in the `FROM` clause and that this uses table aliases.

If you are using an old version of MySQL (as in your fiddle), you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT o.order_id, op.product, op.product_price, op.product_quantity,
       o.order_total,
       (o.order_total -
        (SELECT SUM(op2.product_price * op2.product_quantity)
         FROM orders_products op2 
         WHERE op2.order_id = op.order_id
        ) 
       ) 
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     orders_products op
     ON o.order_id = op.order_id;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/11) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That's great, thanks! Your fiddle is here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/14

Answer (score 0):

You neeed simply nto GROUP By AND some Aggregatin fucntion

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  order_total DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO orders (
  order_id,
  order_total
)
VALUES
  (
    1,
    750
  ),
  (
    2,
    850
  );
  
CREATE TABLE orders_products (
  product VARCHAR(20),
  order_id INT,
  product_quantity INT,
  product_price DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO orders_products (
  product,
  order_id,
  product_quantity,
  product_price
)
VALUES
  (
    'apples',
    1,
    1,
    100
  ),
  (
    'bananas',
    1,
    2,
    200
  ),
  (
    'pineapples',
    2,
    2,
    150
  ),
  (
    'grapes',
    2,
    3,
    50
  ),
  (
    'bananas',
    2,
    1,
    200
  );
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT orders.order_id, orders_products.product, orders_products.product_price, orders_products.product_quantity, orders.order_total
FROM orders_products
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = orders_products.order_id;

| order_id | order_total | product    | product_price | product_quantity |
| -------- | ----------- | ---------- | ------------- | ---------------- |
| 1        | 750         | apples     | 100           | 1                |
| 1        | 750         | bananas    | 200           | 2                |
| 2        | 850         | pineapples | 150           | 2                |
| 2        | 850         | grapes     | 50            | 3                |
| 2        | 850         | bananas    | 200           | 1                |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT orders.order_id
    , GROUP_CONCAT(orders_products.product)
    , orders.order_total - SUM(orders_products.product_price *  orders_products.product_quantity) Diff_1
    , orders.order_total
FROM orders_products
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = orders_products.order_id
GROUP BY order_id,order_total;

| order_id | order_total | GROUP_CONCAT(orders_products.product) | Diff_1 |
| -------- | ----------- | ------------------------------------- | ------ |
| 1        | 750         | apples,bananas                        | 250    |
| 2        | 850         | pineapples,grapes,bananas             | 200    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iGg1g98L9JUioCiDP28bEf/13)